# Android version kitkat giving 500 internal error for POST method Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, server, http-post, retrofit2, internal-server-error

I am new to Android. The problem I am facing is that Android versions below KitKat are giving 500 server error for POST requests using Retrofit, but the same code is working well for later versions i.e. 5.1 and Marshmallow.

What am I missing? Any suggestions please?

My Interface:
public interface LoginService {

```
String API_BASE_URL = "https://penna--pennadev.cs18.my.salesforce.com/";

OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY));

Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
LoginService api = builder.build().create(LoginService.class);


@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({"Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@POST("services/oauth2/token")
Call<DataClass> getAccessToken(
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("username") String adminName,
        @Field("client_id") String client_id,
        @Field("client_secret") String secret,
        @Field("grant_type") String grantType);

@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({"Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
})
@POST("services/apexrest/requestLoc")
Call<String> replaceSFDC(@Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Field("IMEI") String Imei,
        @Field("lat") String latitude,
        @Field("long") String longitude,
        @Field("gps") String gps,
        @Field("connection") String connection,
        @Field("netConnected") String netConnected
);
```

My Service:
        if (isConnected == true) {

```
        Call<DataClass> call = LoginService.api.getAccessToken(".........", "...........@hotmail.com","client_key","client_secret", "grant_type");


        finalCapturedData = db.getAllInfo();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DataClass>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DataClass> call, Response<DataClass> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Access Token : " + response.body().getAccess_token(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    postDeviceState(response.body().getAccess_token());
                    getData();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Can't get response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DataClass> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
private void postDeviceState(String access_token) {

    Call<String> callReplace = LoginService.api.replaceSFDC("OAuth " + access_token,
            finalCapturedData.get(1), finalCapturedData.get(2), finalCapturedData.get(3),
            finalCapturedData.get(4), finalCapturedData.get(5), finalCapturedData.get(6));

    callReplace.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "SFDC ID" + response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Data sent on server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("SFDC ID", response.body());

            //Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Delete " + finalCapturedData.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("Delete : ", finalCapturedData.get(0));

            db.deleteData(Integer.parseInt(finalCapturedData.get(0)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you add your code to your question as text? It'll make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: @MichaelDodd here is the updated version